# Cinder: How to get a pointer to data\frame generated but never shown on screen?

Tags: c++, cross-platform, cinder

There is that grate lib I want to use called [libCinder](http://libcinder.org/), I looked thru [its docs](http://libcinder.org/docs/v0.8.3/) but do not get if it is possible and how to render something with out showing it first?

Say we want to create a simple random color 640x480 canvas with 3 red white blue circles on it, and get RGB\HSL\any `char *` to raw image data out of it with out ever showing any windows to user. (say we have console application project type). I want to use such feaure for server side live video stream generation and for video streaming I would prefer to use [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) so that is why I want a pointer to some RGB\HSV or what ever buffer with actuall image data. How to do such thing with libCInder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use off-screen rendering. `libcinder` seems to be just a wrapper for `OpenGL`, as far as graphics go, so you can use `OpenGL` code to achieve this.

Since `OpenGL` does not have a native mechanism for off-screen rendering, you'll have to use an extension. A tutorial for using such an extension, called Framebuffer Rendering, can be found [here](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_fbo.html). You will have to modify `renderer.cpp` to use this extension's commands.

An alternative to using such an extension is to use [`Mesa 3D`](http://www.mesa3d.org/), which is an open-source implementation of `OpenGL`. `Mesa` has a software rendering engine which allows it to render into memory without using a video card. This means you don't need a video card, but on the other hand the rendering might be slow. `Mesa` has an example of rendering to a memory buffer at `src/osdemos/` in the Demos `zip` file. This solution will probably require you to write a complete `Renderer` class, similar to `Renderer2d` and `RendererGl` which will use `Mesa`'s intrusctions instead of `Windows`'s or `Mac`'s.

Comment: `Renderer` class analog of `RendererGl` would make Cinder crossplatform...=) That would be grate! But I am 2 lazy and  2 stupid for it...